# How do I access an IP from outside AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, kubernetes, amazon-ec2, cloud

I have a EC2 instance on AWS with a particular IP. I ssh into this EC2 instance using

```
ssh <username>@<IP>
```

I have a kubernetics service running on my EC2 instance as follows:

```
service/ajinkya                         ClusterIP      10.152.183.62    <none>         9999/TCP            18d
```

I have a client service running outside AWS (my macOS laptop), this client requires me to access the IP of kubernetics service as follows:

```
client = kfp.Client('http://10.152.183.62:9999')
```

When I ssh into AWS I can use this client IP http://10.152.183.62:9999 through AWS. But I cannot access this IP <10.152.183.62:9999> directly from my MacOS. How can I access this IP from outside AWS ?

Comment: The 10.x.x.x addresses are non-routable, private addresses (RFC1918). Replace that in the URL with the public IP that you're using for SSH and ensure that port 9999 is open to the same IPs as port 22 (assuming that meets your security requirements). If that doesn't work, ensure that your Kubernetes configuration is set to listen on an interface that's reachable remotely, not 127.0.0.1).

Answer (score 1):

To do that to change your service to be a LoadBalancer type instead of ClusterIP.

Take a look at the [definition of this service type](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types):

> LoadBalancer: Exposes the Service externally using a cloud provider's load balancer. NodePort and ClusterIP Services, to which the external load balancer routes, are automatically created.

Once you create the LoadBalancer service, you will get an external IP assign to your service (it may take some minutes), and then you can use this address to access your application from outside your cloud provider.